# Rails: Refactoring code for DRY method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have some code in which I loop through pieces of data and I am having to write the same code more than once, and I am wanting to "DRY it up".

Here is some of the code:

```
<%= raw @artist["albums"]["Albums"].uniq_by{ |a| a["Genre"] }.collect { |album| link_to album["Genre"], genre_path(CGI::escape(album["Genre"])) unless album["Artist"]["Name"] != @term }.join(" ") %>
```

The piece that I am having to duplicate multiple times is the end `unless album["Artist"]["Name"] != @term` is there anyway to filter an array better than having to write this unless statement everytime?

hope that makes sense

I was able to shorten the code by doing removing the `uniq_by`

```
<%= raw @artist["albums"]["Albums"].collect { |album| link_to album["Genre"], genre_path(CGI::escape(album["Genre"])) unless album["Artist"]["Name"] != @term }.uniq.join(" ") %>
```

Comment: Well you could write a helper method, but I think you need to reconsider this line of code from the beginning. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: well I am trying to collect all unique genres where the artist name is equal to the `@term` variable... sorry if the code is sloppy.. still learning Ruby :P

Comment: So you just want a list of the artist's genres?

Comment: yes, essentially they just need to be unique to remove duplicates

Comment: Well, you can do that with `@artist.genres.uniq.map{|genre| genre.title}.join(",")` or something similar if you've set up the association properly.

Comment: yeah... the only issue is that this is all coming back from an API so its one big multi-dimensional array... wish it was coming from the DB...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are emulating a GROUP BY query in your view.  In particular your `@term` clause looks like a `WHERE` condition or a join constraint.

If you have an Album model around, I'd add one or more [named scopes](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html) representing parts of the query, and then just chain those together in your view (with a `collect` at the end to format link tags.)